# Get a variable value in the url using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new in ajax. In this code how I can get the value of variable 'zero' in a.php?

It's the code :

HTML:

```
 <div class="div1"></div>
 <button>Click</button>
```

AJAX:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         var zero = $('#query').valueOf();;
         $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('button').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            url : "a.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : zero,
            success: function(result){
                    $('.div1').html(result);
            }                               
            });
         });
      });
 </script>
```

a.php :

```
 <?php
    $zero = $_POST['data'];
    echo $zero;
 ?>
```

Comment: pass data in ajax like this data:{'zero':zero} and in a.php write this $zero=$_POST['zero'];

Comment: not data ;instead data{'var':zero } in ajax code  and $_POST['var']

Comment: It shows an error 'Undefined index: var'  @N.M.N

Comment: does the code above my comment work?? by abhijit?then thats fine

Comment: No bro same error shows. I find my solution in '1 Answer' below my question.Thanks both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

While sending data, send it as key=value pair. In your case, in the ajax request change data like this.

data : "zero="+zero

While accessing in Php do this

$zero = $_POST['zero'];

Comment: Sorry to intefere . cant u please make me understand the key value pair and why we adding this + symbol for data?

Comment: To append the string and variable.